# Больные и болельщики

Tags: омонимы

Как мы знаем, поклонники той или иной спортивной команды называются болельщики. А поддерживать свою любимую команду, переживать за нее - болеть. При этом "болеть" - значит находиться в состоянии недуга, подорванного здоровья.
А какая связь между этими понятиями? Чувствую, что это не простое совпадение.)))

Answer (score 3):

Если быть точным, то слово болельщик происходит от слова болеть в значении "переживать".
В словаре С.И.Ожегова к этому слову дается пометка: разговорное. Также отмечается, что одно из переносных значений слова "болеть" - "болеть за кого-либо, что-либо", означает остро переживать успехи и неудачи чего-либо, кого-либо.
В словаре Т.Ф.Ефремовой также слово "болельщик" трактуется как разговорное.
О прямой связи слов "болезнь" и "болельщик" нигде не говорится. У этих слов общий корень: "бол".
Слово "болельщик" относительно молодое. Его нет в словаре В.И.Даля. Но там есть значение, не связанное со словом "болезнь" - "Добрый начальник болеет о всех..." (см.статью на слово "Боль")
Когда слово "болельщик" пришло в русский язык - точно не известно. В XX веке оно уже было. Вероятно, его появление связано с началом популярности футбола в России (1912 - первый чемпионат).
Слово "фанат" пришло в русский язык совсем недавно (с распадом СССР). Оно пришло с запада, где болельщиков называли словами "фан" (Англия и др), "тифози" (Италия). Неологизм "фанат" - это молодёжное словотворчество из слов "фан" и "фанатик".

источник: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/528346-bolelschik-ot-slova-bolezn-chto-v-etom-slove.html

Answer (score 0):

В одной из современных радиопередач по русскому языку приводилась версия, что в дореволюционные времена существовало разговорное слово "болейщик" (от слова "футбол" или других игр с мячом - неясно), которое по созвучию со словом "болеть/радеть за" со временем и дало обозначение людям, которые любят смотреть футбол (болеть за команду), формально, "любителям футбола" (сейчас пресса стала употреблять языческое "поклонники футбола").

Answer (score 0):

"Болельщик" - "калька" с итальянского "tifosi" (обратное заимствование представляется маловероятным, да и значение у итальянцев шире).

Answer (score 0):

И те, и другие болеют. Но первые - любители, а вторые - профессионалы. Надеюсь, -щик - это суффикс, указывающий на профессию))